# How to navigate to the first and last page antd Pagination (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In my table component my pagination options are as below :

```
const showTotal = (total, range) => {
  return `${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total}`
};

const  renderPagination=(current, type, originalElement)=>{
  if (type === 'prev') {
    return <a className="table-prev" >Previous</a>;
  } if (type === 'next') {
    return <a>Next</a>;
  }
  return originalElement;

}
  return (
   <Table
   className="process-table-container"
   size='middle'
   columns={columns}
   dataSource={tableData}
   pagination={{
    pageSize: 10,
    showSizeChanger: true,
    itemRender:(current, type, originalElement)=>renderPagination(current, type, originalElement),
    showTotal: showTotal,
    className: 'pagination'
    }}
   />
  )
}
```

I have the next and previous options in `itemRender` but no first and last options how to do it without using custom pagination or table wrapper?

> the output should be like this 
>   [image]

i made the numbers as display none

Comment: Antd pagination always shows the first and last page, why do you need different buttons for the same?

Comment: No it doesn't show first and last can you provide me a reference if it does

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xlnmyvryr) from docs where 1 and 20 are always visible

Comment: i've updated the question for better undrestanding

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `showQuickJumper` which is more generic and readable than adding two more buttons for `first` and `last`:

```js
<Table
   ...
   pagination={{
    ...,
    itemRender:(current, type, originalElement)=>renderPagination(current, type, originalElement),
    ...,
    showQuickJumper: true
    }}
/>
```

[image: GoTo]

Demo:

[image: Edit compassionate-monad-gzrkt]

---

If you still want to add two buttons, you need to disable pagination `pagination={false}` and make new wrapper component which wraps `Table` with your custom pagination.

```js
function TableWrapper(props) {
  // Pagintation state...
  ...
  return (
      <TableWithFirstLast>
         // Use Table component with pagination={false}
         // Use Pagination component
         // Add first and last work with Pagination
         // Control how much data need to be shown on table's dataSource
      <TableWithFirstLast/>
  );
}
```

Comment: can u make the setup for the image that i've posted as the output ?

Comment: Did you try by yourself? it's out of the scope of your question, I answered what you asked, feel free to ask another question and send me a link.

Comment: no i just wanted the pagination to be in that format what i put in the image .is there a way to do it in antd table

Comment: It's not free coding service, try first

Comment: i had tried a lot managed to get the Previous and next but couldn't get first and last , all i need is the first and last jumper

Comment: You need to make `TableWithFirstLast` wrapper, and use `first` and `last` state, I showed you what needs to be done, try it, there is some work to it.